# How To retrieve third highest salary and alongwith the name of employee from a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table named "tblEmployee"..in which two columns are as "EmpName" and "Salary"...
5 rows in this table are:

```
| EmpName | Salary |
|---------|--------|
| john    |  80000 |
| ann     |  20000 |
| james   |  40000 |
| smith   |  90000 |
| rudolph |  30000 |
```

I want to retrieve third highest salary from tblEmployee table alongwith the name of employee.
i.e. my output should be **james,40000**  in this case.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server 2005+:

```
WITH cteRowNums AS (
    SELECT EmpName, Salary,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM tblEmployee
)
SELECT EmpName, Salary
    FROM cteRowNums
    WHERE RowNum = 3;
```

To allow for the possibility of ties, you could replace the `ROW_NUMBER()` function with `DENSE_RANK()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 EmpName, Salary FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS E 
ORDER BY E.Salary ASC
```

i.e. select the top 3 employees by salary then reverse the order of them and select the top 1.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i want to point out in the above answer if the row number is used which will not work if there are duplicate records in the table. You will have to end up using the distinct else the above query will not yield the correct result.

There are many ways to achieve the same functionality. If you just need to find the maximum salary then you could use

```
Select Max(Salary) from Employees
```

SQL query to find 2nd Highest salary in the employee table using subquery

```
Select Max(Salary) from Employees where Salary < (Select Max(Salary) from Employees)
```

SQL query to find nth highest salary in the employee table using using subquery

```
 SELECT TOP 1 SALARY
FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT TOP N SALARY
      FROM EMPLOYEES
      ORDER BY SALARY DESC
      ) RESULT
ORDER BY SALARY
// Replace the N with the highest number which you need to find.
```

SQL query to find nth highest salary in the employee table using CTE

```
 WITH RESULT AS
(
    SELECT SALARY,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS DENSERANK
    FROM EMPLOYEES
)
SELECT TOP 1 SALARY
FROM RESULT
WHERE DENSERANK = N
```

To get the 3rd Highest salary in the employee table

```
WITH RESULT AS
    (
        SELECT SALARY,EmpName,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS DENSERANK
        FROM EMPLOYEES
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 SALARY,EmpName 
    FROM RESULT
    WHERE DENSERANK = 3
```

You can find out more details about the same in my blog [How to find nth highest salary using SQL query](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-find-nth-highest-salary-using-sql-query/)